# Doha connection is 25 minutes: timing changed after we purchased tickets

Tags: lhr, short-connections, doha, krabi

We are flying from Heathrow to Krabi via Doha on Sunday. We recenty noticed that, after buying the tickets, the connection time in Doha changed and now we only get 25 minutes for our connection. We've been to Doha before and we had 45 minutes and we had to rush to make it.

Now we have a feeling we might not make it in time, especially if there is a delay to take off. Is this worth worrying about? We got flights on the same ticket so I know, in case we miss it, the airline would put us on next flight, however, the next flight is the next day.

Comment: I'd call the airline to discuss it. They might have someone meet you at arrivals and escort you to your next flight, giving you priority service through transfers.

Answer (score 5):

Call the airline and mention that you've been rescheduled and you now feel you have a connection that's too tight to make.  I've had this happen with both Air Canada and United Airlines, and both times, when I called the airline, they were happy to make some changes to my schedule to give me a more comfortable connection.  (Air Canada was also willing to do this for me when my two-hour connection turned into an eight-hour connection on a flight out of JFK home; they were even willing to do it out of another airport - LGA - since I wasn't too concerned about which airport out of NYC I used.)